# Getting selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I have a selenium automation code where I am  getting

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument

I think it is related to URL that I am sending through command line, Its what causing 'InvalidArgumentException'. I am passing the URL like this

> "https://www.hotstar.com"

Below is my code

test_mycode.py

```
from datetime import datetime

def test_Openurl(setup):
    driver = setup["driver"]
    url = setup["URL"]

    try:
        before_time = datetime.now().strftime('%H%M%S%f')  
        driver.get(url)
        now_time = datetime.now().strftime('%H%M%S%f')  
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.message)

    assert driver.current_url == URL
    driver.save_screenshot("ss.png")
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    driver.save_screenshot("ss1.png")
    driver.close()
```

My Conftest.py has no issue in it, the setup is passed, I genuinely feel that the issue is in the format of URL.

The error that I am getting is

```
     "call": {
            "duration": 0.004477769000004628,
            "outcome": "failed",
            "crash": {
                "path": "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
                "lineno": 247,
                "message": "selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument\n  (Session info: headless chrome=90.0.4430.72)\nStacktrace:\n#0 0x55f76d8bfe89 <unknown>"
            },
```

Which is related to invalid URL, The command through which I am passing the URL is

> pytest -v -s --json-report --json-report-indent=4 --json-report-file=report/report.json --html=report/report.html test_mycode.py --url "https://www.hotstar.com"

Comment: I think the error lies here : `print(e.message)` does exception object has any message attribute? Try printing exception as a string

Comment: Why do you print `e.message` ? The error you get is only ralted to that. If you want to get the real debuging message, remove the try except...

Comment: @AnkushPandit  sure thanks, but the exception I am getting could be because of the URL, Any idea about that?

Comment: @Fredericka Would that solve the issue ? cause I got some exception that's why it jumped to exception block

Comment: Try removing the try except block and tells us the message, this will be more usefull

Comment: @Fredericka Sure

Comment: @Fredericka this is what i am getting                                                                              `  "outcome": "failed",
                "crash": {
                    "path": "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
                    "lineno": 247,
                    "message": "selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument\n  (Session info: headless chrome=90.0.4430.72)\nStacktrace:\n#0 0x55f76d8bfe89 <unknown>"
                },`